# Use latitude & longitude to determine which "cell" I am located in (NETCDF4)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, netcdf, coordinate-systems, netcdf4

**Background**

I have a NETCDF4 file with grid size `0.125x0.125`. The latitudes go from `90` to `-90` and longitudes go from `0` to `360`. The full table size is therefore `1441 x 2880` (latitudes x longitudes).

I am taking my location coordinates  (lat lon in degrees) and trying to locate which `cell` I am in...

To calculate in which `cell` I am in, I do this:

```
'''
This function takes an array and a value.
It finds the item in the array for which the value most closely matches, and returns the index.
'''
def GetNearestIndex(arrayIn, value):
    distance = math.fabs(arrayIn[0] - value);
    nearest = 0;
    index = 0
    for idx, val in enumerate(arrayIn):
        delta_distance = math.fabs(val - value)
        if delta_distance < distance:
            nearest = val
            index = idx
            distance = delta_distance
    return index

#Lats and Longs arrays from the NETCDF4 dataset
lats = dataset.variables['latitude'][:]
longs = dataset.variables['longitude'][:]

#GetNearestIndex finds the item in the array for which the value most closely matches, and returns the index.
nearestLatitudeIndex = Utilities.GetNearestIndex(lats,  myLat)
nearestLongitudeIndex = Utilities.GetNearestIndex(longs, myLon%360)
```

So given my NECTDF4 dataset, if my location is `[31.351621, -113.305864]` (lat, lon), I find that I am matched with `cell` [31.375, 246.75] (lat, lon). Plugging the calculated lat and lon into `GetNearestIndex`, I will then have the "address" (x, y) of the cell in which I am located.

Now that I know in which `cell` I am closest to, I take the value from the NETCDF file and I can then say something like "The temperature at your location is X".

The problem is, I do not know if I am doing this correctly, so hence my question:

**Questions**

1. How do I correctly determine which cell I am located in and get the
   x and y indexes?
2. How can I verify that my calculation is correct?
3. Is myLon%360 the correct way to convert from myLon to a grid that
   goes from 0 to 360 degrees? Does the grid cell size not matter?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to check / test your approach but I would use numpy, the library on which NetCDF4 is based. `geo_idx()` below, is what I use for a regular grid of lat/lon degrees, with lons between -180 and 180. This approach avoids looping thru all lat / lon arrays.

```
  import numpy as np
  import netCDF4

  def geo_idx(dd, dd_array):
    """
     - dd - the decimal degree (latitude or longitude)
     - dd_array - the list of decimal degrees to search.
     search for nearest decimal degree in an array of decimal degrees and return the index.
     np.argmin returns the indices of minium value along an axis.
     so subtract dd from all values in dd_array, take absolute value and find index of minium.
   """
    geo_idx = (np.abs(dd_array - dd)).argmin()
    return geo_idx
```

To use and test

```
  # to test
  in_lat = 31.351621
  in_lon = -113.305864

  nci = netCDF4.Dataset(infile)
  lats = nci.variables['lat'][:]
  lons = nci.variables['lon'][:]
  # since lons are 0 thru 360, convert to -180 thru 180
  converted_lons = lons - ( lons.astype(np.int32) / 180) * 360

  lat_idx = geo_idx(in_lat, lats)
  lon_idx = geo_idx(in_lon, converted_lons)
  print lats[lat_idx]
  print converted_lons[lon_idx]
```